# Java smallest number out of 5

Tags: java

Given the following class with a method to get the weight, how would I write a class that can contain many of them and write a method to find the one with the largest weight?

```
public class Item{
    int weight;
    public int GetWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
}

public class ItemContainer{
    Item[] items;
    public Item GetMaxWeight(){
        //find Item with largest weight
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Google - find max array. And delete this question afterwards.

Comment: You could put the whole object into the array and sort it if you define the equals method or a comparator.

Comment: What have you got so far?  Do you know how the input/output of the program should look like? @FailedDev I think your advice is unlikely to help OP. It's only a small part of OP's troubles.

Comment: why not use a simple iteration? :)

Comment: I already wrote this in the OP, but clearly it got edited out. I can't use an array because I can't get the name after finding the highest weight easily. There must be an easier way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variable to track it as well.

```
YourObject maxWeight = null; // The temp to determine the max
YourObject current = new YourObject(); // The current object you're storing input into

// Get Data for current from whatever source you're using
if (maxWeight == null || current.getWeight() > maxWeight.getWeight())
    maxWeight = current;

// Do other processing and get the rest of the data
System.out.println(maxWeight.getName() + " has the maximum weight.");
```

Comment: I think this will work, thanks so much! Let me try it.

Comment: Whoa, you can earn a checkmark for a homework answer by *doing the OP's homework?* Neat.

Comment: I suppose I gave too much information which wasn't my intention, I didn't know how to word it the right way without any code examples :(

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I believe this answer was the best, not because "he did my homework", which isn't necessarily true, but because it's one of the very few that didn't suggest arrays, which I didn't want to use in the first place. This is a simple, concise solution, one that I can understand and use without just copying it out of here.

Comment: @linkxs dlev, as far as I can tell was saying the same thing that I did essentially, he just didn't give you what I gave you. I really shouldn't have given so much code but I just couldn't find a way to explain it.

Comment: @izuriel After reading dlev's post, I didn't think of putting a statement after each input, after reading yours, I got it. So yeah, I guess both are right. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: I'm really not fishing for a check here; I was merely pointing out that the code posted is a complete solution, which definitely isn't ideal for homework problems. @linkxs I'm glad you understand it better now; hopefully you'll be able to apply what you learned in the future.

Comment: @dlev Yea, I realize that now. It won't happen again. If I can't come up with a written explanation I'll just bypass answering.

Answer (score 3):

I would not utilize sorting to solve this problem. A sort is useful when you care about the absolute order of *all* elements in a collection. In your case, though, you only care about a single element that is "bigger" than all the rest.

Think about what is it about that element that makes it the biggest. How can you tell if it is bigger or smaller than another element? How can you keep track of that?

Comment: +1: Much more efficient in terms of space and time than an explicit sort.

Answer (score 2):

If your objects are in a `List` called `yourObjects` :

```
Collections.sort(yourObjects, new Comparator<YourClass>(){ 

  @Override
  public int compareTo(YourClass o){
    return weight - o.weight; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Be wary of implementing `compareTo()` for integral types by simple subtraction, since it could overflow.

Comment: He could also store the highest in a temp var, without having to sort the array

Comment: We haven't learned this yet, and frankly I'd prefer to use things I actually understand. There has to be a simpler way to do this

Answer (score 1):

If your objects are stored in an array called `yourObjectArray` :

```
YourClass max = yourObjectArray[0];
for(YourClass o : yourObjectArray){
  if(max.getWeight() < o.getWeight() ){
    max = o;
  }
}
```

max will then contain the object with the higher weight.
If you are just interested in the weight, `max` can directly store the weight instead of the whole object.